# I Submitted the solution and got time limit error in 4th test case

Tags: c++, stl

[This is a problem on *codeforces*](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/239/A)
and I have submitted a solution and I got TLE.
How to remove TLE

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    unsigned int y, k, n;
    set <int> s;
    cin >> y >> k >> n;
    if (y >= n)
    {
        cout << -1; return 0;
    }
    for (int i = y + 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (i%k == 0)
        {
            s.insert(i - y);
        }
    }
    if (s.begin() == s.end())
    {
        cout << -1; return 0;
    }
    for (auto x : a)
        cout << x << " ";
}
```

Comment: While you're waiting for an answer, please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5470596) and [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5470596) ;)

Comment: But before that, [edit] your question to explain what you're program is supposed to do, and how it does it. That's considered better than simply pointing to a link nobody will follow.

Comment: You need to come up with a smarter algorithm.

Comment: Where, oh where, did you get the idea of using #include<bits/stdc++.h>  ??  Wherever that is you should stop getting ideas from there

Comment: _@VaibhavPandey_ Stop wasting your time with such _online code judge_ engines. Go and work through a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Comment: You have provided no input, nor expected output, nor duration ... see [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems at the algorithmic level. Instead to generate all candidate `i` values and then test if they are divisible by `k`, you can directly generate these values in a loop with an increment equal to `k`.

The minimum value `imin`is equal to `k*((y+1)/k)` or `k*((y+1)/k) + k`, depending if `y+1` is divisible by `k`or not.

You have two gains: you consider `k` less candidates, and you avoid the costly `%` operation.

Moreover, when you find a value, you can directly print it, no need to memorize it.

Edit: here is the code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    unsigned int y, k, n;
    std::cin >> y >> k >> n;

    unsigned int imin = k*((y+1)/k);
    if (imin < y+1) imin += k;
    if (imin > n) {
        std::cout << -1;
        return 0;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = imin; i <= n; i+=k)
    {
        std::cout << i-y << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit 2: the last `i-y` calculation can be avoided by changing the bounds  of the loop